# Sum of two normal numbers need not be a normal one

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Using the translation invariance of Lebesgue measure how to show that sum and difference of two normal numbers need not be normal ?

Normal number in $(0,1]$ is a number $\omega$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_i(w) = \frac{1}{2}$

Hint Enough.

Comment: Should there be a division by $n$  somewhere before the sum, so that one is averaging the digits up to the $n$th? (and *then* taking the limit)

Comment: Actually, if one doesn't know what normal means one would not even guess that $d_i(\omega)$ denotes the $i$th binary digit of $\omega$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac13=&\,0.010101\ldots\\
\frac23=&\,0.101010\ldots\\
1=&\,0.111111\ldots
\end{align*}
in binary. $1/3$ and $2/3$ are normal, $1$ is not.

---

If you insist on using translation invariance, suppose—for the sake of contradiction—that sums and differences of normal numbers are always normal. This implies that if $x$ is *not* normal and $y$ is, then $x\oplus y$ is necessarily non-normal, where $$x\oplus y\equiv\begin{cases}x+y&\text{if $x+y\leq 1$,}\\x+y-1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
is the “come-back-from-the-left-once-left-to-the-right” sum of $x\in(0,1]$ and $y\in(0,1]$.

Now let $N$ be the set of normal numbers in $(0,1]$ and $x$ a non-normal number. Then, $x\oplus N\subseteq N^c$ by the foregoing. However, by Borel's normal-number theorem and the translation invariance of the Lebesgue measure,
$$1=\lambda(N)=\lambda(x\oplus N)\leq\lambda(N^c)=0,$$
a contradiction.